# label and value reposition to same row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I just created webpage, but in that page label and value in different locations , like below

[image]

this is the view page code snippet

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Label[i].NameEn, Model.Label[i].NameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })//Label  
    <div class="col-md-10">     
        @Html.Raw(Model.val[i].Value_EN)  //Value                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle of rendered HTML

Comment: You have 1 extra  closing </div> in your code

Comment: @Dilip just corrected

Comment: your issue fixed ?

Comment: @Dilip not yet , I cant figure it out

Comment: @kelumpriyadarshane, hope your issue is fixed

Comment: @jamiedanq yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer myself

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

           <div class="form-group">
                   @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Label[i].NameEn, Model.Label[i].NameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })//Label 
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-control">
                      @Html.Raw(Model.val[i].Value_EN)  //Value
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.Label("My Label 1", new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        @Html.TextBox("My Label 1", "My Label Message1", 
            new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.Label("Error Message", new { @class = "form-label" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using **`bootstrap`** you should be mindful of how you use your `col-md col-sm col-xs` etc.

If you do it this way it should align them

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Label[i].NameEn, Model.Label[i].NameEn,       htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })//Label  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">     
        @Html.Raw(Model.val[i].Value_EN)  //Value                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Or put them again in another `DIV`

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <div>
        <div class="col-md-2>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Label[i].NameEn, Model.Label[i].NameEn,       htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })//Label  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">     
            @Html.Raw(Model.val[i].Value_EN)  //Value                      
        </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helped